# cakephp cookie not working or not set on server but working on localhost

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies

in my project,
i wish to add favorites or remove favorites for the selected properties

below code i used to do task.. its working well on localhost..

```
public function add_favourites(){

   if($this->request->is('ajax') or $this->request->is('post')){  
   $Fav_cookie = $this->Cookie->read('Fav_cookie');
    if(isset($Fav_cookie)){
         $add_fav = $this->request->data['prop_id'];
         $Fav_cookie .= "_".$add_fav;    
         $this->Cookie->write('Fav_cookie', $Fav_cookie, false, '1 Month');
     }else{
         $add_fav = $this->request->data['prop_id'];
         $this->Cookie->write('Fav_cookie', $add_fav, false, '1 Month'); 
     }
     $count_fav = $this->Cookie->read('Fav_cookie');
     $count_fav1 = explode("_",$count_fav);
     echo count($count_fav1);
   }
   exit;
```

}

```
public function remove_favourites(){

   if($this->request->is('ajax') or $this->request->is('post')){

     $count_fav = $this->Cookie->read('Fav_cookie');
     $count_fav1 = explode("_",$count_fav);
     if(isset($count_fav1)){

          $remove_fav = $this->request->data['prop_id'];
          if(($key = array_search($remove_fav,$count_fav1)) !== false) {
              unset($count_fav1[$key]);

               }
           }
           echo count($count_fav1);
           $count_fav2= implode("_",$count_fav1);
           $this->Cookie->write('Fav_cookie', $count_fav2, false, '1 Month');
        }
        exit;
   }
```

but i used the same code on live server...

the add favorites is working well.. but remove favorites not working..

the issue is live server only

cookie is not set or write after removing the favorites..

sorry for my english....

pls help me to solve it...

Comment: Check permission for folder app/tmp.

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird  Yes, i checked permission.. it has 777 only... yes i m indian.. working for company

Comment: See if project is working on Local , it must work on Live server too.I think you try clearing cache folder on live.Or do 1 thing Try uploading ALL APP folder contents on live (means relpace all LIVE by LOCAL contents).

Comment: Did it work when i told u to Replace all LIVE by  Local files ?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird - i dont replace the LIVE.. i did only change the code on specific file.. thanks

Comment: Anayway i told you that LOCAL file have something Different than LIVE so behave differently and The Trick worked :) Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code between if conditions these 2 lines

```
 $count_fav2= implode("_", $count_fav1);
 $this->Cookie->write('Fav_cookie', $count_fav2, false, '1 Month');
```

Code:

```
public function remove_favourites(){

  if($this->request->is('ajax') or $this->request->is('post')){

       $count_fav = $this->Cookie->read('Fav_cookie');
       $count_fav1 = explode("_",$count_fav);
       if(isset($count_fav1)){
           $remove_fav = $this->request->data['prop_id'];
           if(($key = array_search($remove_fav,$count_fav1)) !== false) {
                unset($count_fav1[$key]);
           }
           $count_fav2= implode("_",$count_fav1);
           $this->Cookie->write('Fav_cookie', $count_fav2, false, '1 Month');
       }
       echo count($count_fav1);
    }
    exit;


  }
```

now its working on local and live server..

thanks